# Create a PDF for iPhone, how to?

Tags: iphone, pdf

I'm trying to write a eBook, for the iPhone, using PDF format.

The problem is, I can't create a PDF with 5 cm x 5 cm (example).

I've tried Adobe Acrobat Pro 9. Didn't work, since it is not possible to custom the paper size.

I've tried Pages 08, but it's also not possible (it's possible to set the custom size, but it doesn't work, might be a bug).

I've tried Microsoft Word. The generated PDF is a mess... Doesn't work right.

So.. I can't create a PDF, with a custom paper size. This is nuts... There must be a tool or something that works right.

Anyone knows any tool that works well?

Thanks

Comment: My iPod Touch renders PDFs quite nicely using a normal page size.

Answer (score 3):

On the Mac (since the underlying drawing system Quartz is based on the same ancestor as PDF), you can always generate PDFs by doing Print->Save as PDF...

This generally gives good results.

Comment: I've been able to use Pages. To solve my problem with page sizes, I had to delete the Pages preferences file. Solved. Tks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have only a suggestion, but maybe open office?

Comment: and, btw, open office does work
select tools, page (page tab), user defined, enter the size and go!

Answer (score 0):

Given that the iPhone resolution is 320 x 360px with a resolution of 163ppi we need to optimise print settings before exporting our document to PDF. I’m tipping most people will view their document with the iphone orientated in landscape mode so we’ll base our document width on 360px.

So here’s the settings you need to use when exporting or printing your document to PDF:

Width: 125mm x 225mm.

That’s it.  Now just print your document to PDF using a PDF printer driver like doPDF and email the document to your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at latex. You can typeset the document to any size that you want. http://www.latex-project.org/